# ARM-GCC build error under Fedora 21

Tags: linux, gcc, raspberry-pi, arm, fedora-21

I'm trying to build GCC for ARM under Fedora 21 but 4.6.4 and 4.9.2 fails with same error:

```
checking dynamic linker characteristics... configure: error: Link tests are not allowed after GCC_NO_EXECUTABLES.
Makefile:8200: recipe for target 'configure-zlib' failed
```

I follow this guide: http://www.kunen.org/uC/gnu_tool.html

Can't understand, what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. `configure` command:

```
../../src/gcc-4.9.2/configure --target=arm-none-eabi --prefix=$MYTOOLS --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --enable-languages="c,c++" --with-newlib --with-headers=../../src/newlib-1.20.0/newlib/libc/include/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have zlib installed on this system, you could try adding --with-system-zlib to the configure command you're using.